# Iterate With jQuery .each() method and grab the current iteration

Tags: jquery, each

```js
var selector = $("li.has-submenu .level-2").has("ul#specific-id");
var anchor = $("#specific-id > li > a");
$(selector).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // iterate over all anchor tags
    anchor.each(function() {
      // do extra stuff only if this is the current iteration receiving the enter key press
      var sort = $(this).parent();
      if (index == sort.index()) {
        window.open(this.href);
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="menu level-1">
  <li>No Submenu</li>
  <li>No Submenu</li>
  <li class="has-submenu level-2">
    <a>I'm a Menu With Submenu</a>
    <ul id="specific-id">
      <li class="menuitem">
        <a href="#">List Items A</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menuitem">
        <a href="#">List Item B</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menuitem">
        <a href="#">List Item C</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>No Submenu</li>
  <li>No Submenu</li>
  <li>No Submenu</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I want to grab and open the current URL receiving the enter key press within the submenu level-2.

The jquery selector is to filter the list with a submenu carrying a special ID. And the iteration is to iterate over all the list items within the special id and grab the url from the current list receiving the "Enter" key press.

Thanks

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: @j08691

 I believe the code should be reproducible now. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this. As the elements from which you are getting the URL (from their `href`) are anchors (`<a>`) - wouldn't it be the default behaviour of the browser to open these URLs when their corresponding anchors receive an [Enter] key press?

Comment: So you want the url for `List Item B` to open in a new window/tab or do you want pressing enter triggers all of anchor in the specific-id to open in new window/tab?

Comment: @76484 thought the same but the binding is on the list item hence my comment above

Comment: @Huangism I'll appreciate it if you have a different way of grabbing the respective url from the dom element on the 'Enter' key press and then open the link either via _self or _blank without jquery.

Comment: I think your selector is far too complicated. I think you would get by with `$('#specific-id a')`.

Comment: @Huangism I want the URL of the List item receiving the enter key to open in a new tab.

Comment: @76484 No, cos the <a></a> is placed within a list. And I must mention that the UX is targeted toward achieving an A11Y UI. Arrow key up and down and then enter to open the current list item.

Comment: The list doesn't matter. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/sdgmwx1q/ - but note that the links _already open when clicked or when [Enter] is pressed on them_.

Comment: @Cephas your anchor does not fill the list item itself? To me, your anchor tag should be filling up the space so you would never press enter on the list item since it is not a naturally focusable item. Any press of enter would be on your anchor and it would work naturally without js